# AWS SCP to enforce Tag Policy fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

So I am following this AWS [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/implement-aws-resource-tagging-strategy-using-aws-tag-policies-and-service-control-policies-scps/) to enforce tagging policy across AWS Organization.
I did create the tag policy and the SCP and attached both to the OUs.
Tag policy

```
{
    "tags": {
        "costcenter": {
            "tag_key": {
                "@@assign": "costcenter"
            },
            "tag_value": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "CC102",
                    "CC103",
                    "CC104"
                ]
            },
            "enforced_for": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "ec2:instance"
                ]
            }
        },
        "team": {
            "tag_key": {
                "@@assign": "team"
            },
            "tag_value": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "Team1",
                    "Team2",
                    "Team3"
                ]
            },
            "enforced_for": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "ec2:instance"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SCP

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/team": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to launch an EC2 with non compliant tags, I get the error not authorized with clear message about violating the tag policy

[using non compliant tags error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxRVO.png)

but even when I comply to the policy I get the non authorized message

[using compliant tags error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B671j.png)

Here is the decoded message

```
{
    "DecodedMessage": "{\"allowed\":false,\"explicitDeny\":true,\"matchedStatements\":{\"items\":[{\"statementId\":\"DenyEC2CreationSCP1\",\"effect\":\"DENY\",\"principals\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"AROAY4Z6JOQ4EEGF437YJ\"}]},\"principalGroups\":{\"items\":[]},\"actions\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"}]},\"resources\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*\"},{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*\"}]},\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:RequestTag/costcenter\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"true\"}]}}]}},{\"statementId\":\"Statement1\",\"effect\":\"DENY\",\"principals\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"AROAY4Z6JOQ4EEGF437YJ\"}]},\"principalGroups\":{\"items\":[]},\"actions\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"}]},\"resources\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*\"},{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*\"}]},\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:RequestTag/team\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"true\"}]}}]}},{\"statementId\":\"DenyEC2CreationSCP1\",\"effect\":\"DENY\",\"principals\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"AROAY4Z6JOQ4EEGF437YJ\"}]},\"principalGroups\":{\"items\":[]},\"actions\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"}]},\"resources\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*\"},{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*\"}]},\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:RequestTag/costcenter\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"true\"}]}}]}},{\"statementId\":\"Statement1\",\"effect\":\"DENY\",\"principals\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"AROAY4Z6JOQ4EEGF437YJ\"}]},\"principalGroups\":{\"items\":[]},\"actions\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"}]},\"resources\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*\"},{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*\"}]},\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:RequestTag/team\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"true\"}]}}]}}]},\"failures\":{\"items\":[]},\"context\":{\"principal\":{\"id\":\"AROAY4Z6JOQ4EEGF437YJ:nejla\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:sts::random-account-number:assumed-role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole/nejla\"},\"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\",\"resource\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:random-account-number:volume/*\",\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:Resource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"volume/*\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Account\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"random-account-number\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:AvailabilityZone\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-east-1e\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:Encrypted\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"false\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:VolumeType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"gp2\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"false\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-east-1\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Service\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:VolumeID\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"*\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:VolumeSize\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"8\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:ParentSnapshot\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::snapshot/snap-0c371a5504a01769d\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Type\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"volume\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-east-1\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:ARN\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:random-account-number:volume/*\"}]}}]}}}"
}
```

[Desired outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCEJ9.png)

Comment: Do you actually have permission to create instances? Have you decoded the error message to see what the actual error is?

Comment: Before setting up the SCP, I was able to launch EC2

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are applying those tags to the EBS volumes attached to that EC2 instance as well